# Why can't you put constants in an impl block?

Tags: rust

Why does this code not work?

```rust
pub struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    const THREE: i32 = 3;
    pub fn mul_three(num: i32) -> i32 {
        num * THREE
    }

    pub fn sub_three(num: i32) -> i32 {
        num - THREE
    }
}
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:26,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:5,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:26,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:5,startLineNumber:4),source:%27pub+struct+Foo+%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl+Foo+%7B%0A++++const+THREE:+i32+%3D+3%3B%0A++++pub+fn+mul_three(num:+i32)+-%3E+i32+%7B%0A++++++++num+*+THREE%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++pub+fn+sub_three(num:+i32)+-%3E+i32+%7B%0A++++++++num+-+THREE%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.84123222748815,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1660,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+1.66.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:32.613052010056855,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27rustc+1.66.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+rustc+1.66.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:31.545715762454996,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

It works if the constant is moved up to the module level, or down into the functions. But although it is syntactically allowed where it is at currently, it's not usable:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `THREE` in this scope
 --> <source>:6:15
  |
6 |         num * THREE
  |               ^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

What's the technical reason behind this?

Comment: [The compiler could be more helpful here, so I filed an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/107199).

Comment: @KevinReid: Esteban pouncing in in 3, 2, 1, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prefix it with `Self::` (or `Foo::`), because it is part of the type:

```rust
pub struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    const THREE: i32 = 3;
    pub fn mul_three(num: i32) -> i32 {
        num * Self::THREE
    }

    pub fn sub_three(num: i32) -> i32 {
        num - Self::THREE
    }
}
```